# Template design pattern for operations with parameters

Tags: design-patterns

Template design pattern lets you design an algorithm which can be customized by overriding some template methods.

```
class Algorithm {
    protected void init();
    protected void prepareCup();
    protected TeaBag prepareTeaBag();
    protected void boilWater();
    protected void putWaterIntoCup();
}
```

prepareTeaBag() can return arbitrary tea bags to make custom tea.

But what if I have an algorithm that would require some parameters for operations, for example name of the tea bag, and some other properties that are being changed into each of the operation. I can save those properties into class as a class members but that way I can't call it from different threads. I would need to pass some Context class that would change depending on operation in order to allow multi threading access, or something what are your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a previous project, we used the Template pattern with a context object as follows:

```
abstract class AbstractInvoiceSweep<T extends SweepContext>
{
    public void doSweep(T context);
    protected void calculateTaxes(T context);
    protected void processLines(T context);
    protected void processMemos(T context);
}

class NormalInvoiceSweep extends AbstractInvoiceSweep<SweepContext>
{
    .... 
}

class PrepadiInvoiceSweep extends AbstractInvoiceSweep<PrepaidSweepContext>
{
    ...
}

class SCRInvoiceSweep extends AbstractInvoiceSweep<SCRSweepContext>
{
    ...
}
```

The user of sweep would know the type of context object to prepare based on the type of invoice they are dealing with. The methods in `AbstractInvoiceSweep` use the common attributes defined in `SweepContext` and any specific handling needed will be present in the corresponding subclasses.

Comment: aha, yeah that's should be the case... if some property is needed it will be easily included in context, without significant changes. Thanks bro